# How to uninstall old java version installed with windows 10 updated?

Tags: windows-10, java

My Windows 10 OS, come with an old java version which is 1.7.0.51. 
[windows10 installed with java](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/win10_faq.xml)

it stays at path `Windows\System`

I already use newer version java runtime, how to remove old version installed with windows 10 cleanly?

Comment: The Java VM doesn't come installed by default on any version of Windows.  Java browser extension is something else entirely

Comment: There's no JVM natively installed since Windows XP. Windows 10 certified JVM started from 1.8.0.51, instead of 1.7.x.x. Check Programs & Features to see if older JVM version still exist there, uninstall it with normal way.